# Union if row is null in SQL

Tags: sql

Considering the SQL query below, Person will have an Individual or Company. Keeping this in mind, I made this query to unify the data. I would like it to have only the non-null row of the TaxNumber column (From Individual or Company). But the query returns two columns, the null and the one with the value.

```sql
SELECT
    PR.Id AS PersonId,
    PR.Title AS PersonTitle,
    IA.TaxNumber AS TaxNumber,
    CP.TaxNumber AS TaxNumber
FROM
    person AS PR
    LEFT JOIN individual AS IA ON IA.PersonID = PR.Id
    LEFT JOIN company AS CP ON CP.PersonID = PR.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminology is a bit off which is likey part of the problem in finding a solution.  UNION combines data sets {1,3,5} Union {2,4} gives us {1,2,3,4,5}.  You want to "combine" columns when one is NULL.  `Coalesce()` does this effectively.

`Coalesce()` will return the first non-null value in encountered in a series of objects.   `Coalesce()` is pretty database agnostic (meaning its found in most RDBMS.  However if it does not work: specify what RDBMS you're using; there's likely a similar function.

```
SELECT
    PR.Id AS PersonId,
    PR.Title AS PersonTitle,
    Coalesce(IA.TaxNumber, CP.TaxNumber) AS TaxNumber
FROM
    person AS PR
    LEFT JOIN individual AS IA ON IA.PersonID = PR.Id
    LEFT JOIN company AS CP ON CP.PersonID = PR.Id
```

Examples:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------+
| IA Tax number | CP Tax number | Returns |
+---------------+---------------+---------+
|           123 |        <NULL> |     123 |
|        <NULL> |           456 |     456 |
|           987 |           654 |     987 |
|        <NULL> |        <NULL> |  <NULL> |
+---------------+---------------+---------+
```

So if you want CP tax number to take precedence just switch the order in the coalesce. `Coalesce(CP.TaxNumber, IA.TaxNumber,'MISSING' )`

```
|           987 |           654 |      654 |
|        <NULL> |        <NULL> |  MISSING |
```

Notice I added a 3rd option if we wanted to call out data was 'MISSING' from both sides. but `<NULL>` result would mean the same thing.